# React Native 0.43 upgrade: react@16.0.0-alpha.6 does not satisfy its siblings

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently trying to upgrade my React Native project from 0.38 to 0.43. `react-native-git-upgrade` did not work and thus I tried to upgrade manually. When I try to upgrade my react to @16.0.0-alpha.6, I get the following error:

```
$  npm install --save react@16.0.0-alpha.6
npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "react@16.0.0-alpha.6"
npm ERR! node v4.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@16.0.0-alpha.6 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-native@0.38.1 wants react@~15.4.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-test-renderer@15.4.1 wants react@^15.4.1
```

Does anyone have any pointers or suggestions for me?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem tonite. Deleted node_modules and yarn.lock and ran a fresh yarn install

Comment: I ended up doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem,may be you can update node version to solve it,and you node version(4.3.0) is too old,you should update it to latest.
[image]